# C# - Is there a way to inherit from a generic class with dynamic types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop

I have a repository generic class that handle database operations with Entity Framework.

I want to inherit from this class, but I want this derived class to use different type of table datatypes.

For example, if the base class is called `Repository<TEntity, TContext>` and I want to inherit from it this way `class : Repository<TableTB, someDBContext>`.

Let's say I have more than one table (`TableTB` and `TableTB2`) and more than one `DBContext` (`someDBContext1` and `someDBContext2`) and I want my class to inherit once from

```
class : Repository<TableTB, someDBContext1>
```

and once from

```
class : Repository<TableTB2, someDBContext2>
```

I am not sure if I was able to describe my problem good enough. so tell me what can I add to clarify more.

Comment: You can inherit from a single class in C#. But implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: @Amr Moataz . What is your problem? I don't really understand.

Comment: If I get you correctly, you want your repository to be able to work with two tables in two different contexts?